# There are two dockerfiles that I'm pulling, how do I stop the second docker file without affecting the other one?

Tags: docker, terminal, dockerfile

I'm really sorry but I am completely new to docker.. so I had an error network and I tried pulling again because I thought the first one stop. And this happened..
[image]

How do you stop the second docker file without affecting the first one??

Comment: This doesn’t look wrong… the first one *did* stop.

Comment: but its still running in the terminal.. the first one

Comment: How can you tell?